# OpenVDB error: Q_FOREACH passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2

Tags: c++, qt

I just installed OpenVDB and I'm trying to compile basic examples from [here](http://www.openvdb.org/documentation/doxygen/codeExamples.html) (Ubuntu 14.04 + QtCreator 3.4.0 + GCC_64). The first two examples work just fine, but the third one doesn't - it gives a bunch of errors once I include "LevelSetSphere.h". The most common error says "Q_FOREACH passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2" and refers to the code

```
void foreach(const NodeOp& op, bool threaded = true, size_t grainSize=1)
{
    NodeTransformer<NodeOp> transform(op);
    transform.run(this->nodeRange(grainSize), threaded);
}
```

in NodeManager.h (and other errors refer to different chunks of code in different files of OpenVDB). Does anybody know what I did wrong?

Comment: Qt defines a `foreach` keyword. Don't try to use that name for your own functions.

Comment: I didn't. That's OpenVDB's code. I believe they know how to use `foreach`..

Comment: Are you using Qt at all? Or do you just use the IDE Qt Creator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew Medico was right. OpenVDB defines its own `foreach`, so it's not compatible with Qt. However, if you manually rename all `foreach` inside OpenVDB, you can make it work.

Comment: Valentine: did you use refactor to rename all "foreach"? It's so dangerous, and will be a problem when we update to new openvdb version. Is there anyway to work around it? I have also posted a [question](http://www.openvdb.org/forum/) on OpenVDB forum

Comment: Do not refactor openvdb code: use the solution I provided in my answer instead

Answer (score 4):

To jointly use QT and OpenVDB simply use the following preprocessor instruction before including openvdb.h:

```
#ifdef foreach
  #undef foreach
#endif
#include <openvdb/openvdb.h>

//[...] here foreach is defined by openvdb and there is no foreach QT macro
```

Using this solution you cannot use the QT foreach macro though. You can still use a [ranged based for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) if you are on C++11

Comment: This is valid for Librealsense but not sure about OpenVDB still +1

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because Qt defines a `Q_FOREACH` macro which conflicts with the foreach methods in 'openvdb/util/NodeMask.h'. To remove this conflict, just un-define this macro wherever both openvdb and Qt are being included together. You can look at this Github pull request https://github.com/JimJam42/OpenVDBViewer/pull/1 to get the idea.